# Azure-Devops remove user from projectContributor via Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-rest-api

Using PowerShell  I am attempting to remove a user from groupType projectContributor so I can move him to the Project Team.  I can accomplish the add to the Project Team however I have tried everything I can to remove this users entitlement using a PATCH without success.  FYI to avoid comments, OrgUrl, projectId and userId are being passed.

```
    $b= @"
[
    {
        "op": "remove",
        "path": "/projectEntitlements",
        "value": {
            "projectRef": {
                "id": "$projectID"
            },
            "group": {
                "groupType": "projectContributor"
            }
        }
    }
]
"@

$uri = "$orgURL/_apis/userentitlements/$userId`?api-version=5.1-preview.2"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Body $b -Method PATCH -Headers @{ Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

**The error I am getting is this:**

```
projectId","typeName":"System.ArgumentException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
At line:20 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/json-patch+json ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Any help / examples are appreciated.
I have gone through all the API documentation for Azure DevOps API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$b= @"
[
    {
        "op": "remove",
        "path": "/projectEntitlements/$projectID",
        "value": {
            "projectRef": {
                "id": "$projectID"
            },
            "group": {
                "groupType": "projectContributor"
            }
        }
    }
]
"@
```

And since you are removing value under this path I'm not sure if you need value, so this should provide you the same:

```
$b= @"
[
    {
        "op": "remove",
        "path": "/projectEntitlements/$projectID",
        "value": ""
    }
]
"@
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error using **User Entitlement** rest api.

It worked for me with [**Remove Member From Group**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/remove%20member%20from%20group?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api.

`DELETE https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/GroupEntitlements/{groupId}/members/{memberId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1`

When a user is added to a project as Project Contributors. This user will be added to group `[ProjectName]\\Contributors` of this Project.

You can then use [Group List rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the group id of `[ProjectName]\\Contributors`. The `{memberId}` of above `Remove Member From Group` api is user's `userId`. Then you can just call above api to remove the user from the project contributors group.